# Change the background color in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a theme installed. I just want to make the background darker than what it is, it really helps especially because I have vision problems. I guess I need to use the "Color scheme" from options, but I really couldn't find anything to change the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change **the background color of the Editor tab**, do the following:

1. `File | Settings` (`WebStorm | Preferences` on macOS)
2. `Editor | Color Scheme | General`
3. Make a copy of the Color Scheme (if it's a bundled one or provided by a plugin) so that you can customize it (although the IDE *should* do that for you automatically)
4. Locate `Text | Default text` entry and change the background color there.

An example: modified Dacrula theme with bright yellow background (yeah, looks completely unusable, but good for illustration purposes):
[image]

**Please note:** *some languages* can provide own background colors. E.g. PHP -- a typical PHP-code only file will have all code inside a single `<?php` tag so you may see a different background color for PHP code compared to other languages. Test and adjust it as needed.

**Note #2:** GUI Theme (which is about styling the rest of the IDE GUI): it always linked to some Color Scheme (so the GUI and Editor area have similar colors). When you will be switching between GUI Themes make sure to double check the applied Color Scheme as well (if you need to use your custom one).

**Useful shortcut:** `View | Quick Switch Scheme` -- it will bring a popup menu that allows quickly switching different themes and schemes.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. But the color of the selected layer is the same now, which entry in the color scheme changes that?

Comment: Which "selected layer"? Do you men "current line?" If so -- this would be "Editor | Caret row" on the same screen. If not -- a screenshot with arrows may help here (plus mention the theme/plugin used).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why the hell I used "selected layer", I was trying to mean "selected line", but you got me.